# std::promise set_exception twice cause Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, std-future

Let's say I have a method that calls an unstable third-party service, so I add a timeout for this call say 10 seconds. Here is what I tried:

```
int process()
{
    std::promise<int> promise;
    std::future<int> future = promise.get_future();

    std::thread([&]
    {
        try
        {
            int result = call_third_party_service();
            promise.set_value(result);
        }
        catch (std::exception&) //call_thrid_party_service can throw exceptions
        {
            promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
        }
    }).detach();

    auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    if (status == std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        promise.set_exception(time_out_exception);
    }

    return future.get();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int result = process();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        //print
    }

    //blocks the thread to see what happens
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(1));        
    return 0;
}
```

When `call_third_party_service` is not responding (assume it throws an exception saying timeout after 30 seconds), `status == std::future_status::timeout` hits after 10 seconds' waiting, then `promise.set_exception` works, and everything looks good. However when `call_third_party_service` throws the exception, `promise.set_exception` again, hence the Segmentation fault. What's the correct way to implement this pattern?

Comment: The problem here is that after your timeout the `process` function returns, which means that `promise` ends its life-time and will be destructed. That leaves the thread with a reference to an object that no longer exist. You need to come up with a way to keep the promise alive during the whole life-time of the thread.

Comment: Don't call set_exception in the case of the timeout, just throw the exception directly.

Comment: @Frax Still got segmentation fault. I think the reason is like @Some programmer dude says, `promise` is out of its life cycle.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What do you suggest then? Putting it inside a global container and remove periodically?

Comment: Perhaps using `std::shared_ptr` and capture it by value? I haven't really had time to think about it in that much detail.

Comment: Yeah, throwing the exception directly removes the duplicated call (and makes the code easier to read, really). I read the documentation a bit. You should move your promise to the other thread (the writing end; the promise implements move semantics), and keep only the future on the reading end, no need for shared_ptr.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by `Frax`, you should move the `promise` into the lambda and throw the exception directly when the `future` times out:

```
int process() {
  std::promise<int> promise;
  std::future<int> future = promise.get_future();

  // move ownership of the promise into thread
  std::thread([prom = std::move(promise)]() mutable {
    try {
      int result = call_third_party_service();
      prom.set_value(result);
    } catch (std::exception&)  // call_thrid_party_service can throw exceptions
    {
      prom.set_exception(std::current_exception());
    }
  }).detach();

  auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
  if (status == std::future_status::timeout) {
    // This exception is not part of an asynchronous computation and 
    // should be thrown immediately
    throw time_out_exception("timed out");
  }

  return future.get();
}

int main() {
  try {
    int result = process();
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    // print
  }

  // blocks the thread to see what happens
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(1)); 
  return 0;
}
```